# Is there any replacement for laravel auth ? The make:auth is not working with the latest versions

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have tried to use the command
`php artisan make:auth`
But It says

> \make auth not found

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan make:auth` is for older Laravel versions. Now you can use some of the starter kits, e.g. [Laravel Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze)